# Return type as datatable or List - c#

Tags: c#

A beginner question.

There is DAL class in my application that has following functions

```
public static Datatable GetCustomers()
public static Datatable GetOrderDetails(int orderId)
```

I have been advised that the good practice is to have the return type as a List or class.

so it will be

```
public static List<customer> GetCustomers()
 {
    Datatable dt = ...;
    //then loop through the rows in the table and add to List<customer>
 }
public static order GetOrderDetails(int orderId)
```

I would like to know what are the advantages in the later.

Comment: Having a `List<T>` you can filter it later with LINQ, hook up to items controls in WPF etc

Comment: Well for starters it decouples the implementation (using a data table) from the interface. That allows easier unit testing as well as allowing the implementation to change without affecting clients. Also you could perhaps return an `IEnumerable<Customer>` rather than a list.

Comment: ``List`1`` is a class like ``Datatable`` is

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Will returning IEnumerable<Customer> give better performance ?

Comment: @w.b Both of the advantages you said is available with `Datatable` too.

Comment: @Qwerty No, it won't. If you really want to have the returned value read-only, I recommend taking ``IReadOnlyList`1`` instead.

Comment: @Qwerty No, it's just the most decoupled interface. As Binkan says, you could use `IReadOnlyList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you develop API, it's best to use classes or better interfaces from the `System.Collections.*` and `System.Collections.Generics.*` namespaces, the reason is that you abstract from data access specific technology to basic data structures. These types are much easier to consume from other languages or if you need to convert your result to another format, like *json* or *XML*. It's also easier to query it using LINQ.

`DataTable` requires a dependency on `System.Data` assembly which you may not want to add, especially if you later decide to use another database.

Testing is a breeze with basic plain data structures and pain in a bum if you use specific database library as you need to mock it or use other esoteric techniques.

Answer (score 4):

The latter explicitly defines the contract to the consumer of your DAL, so they don't have to guess whats in the datatable, its inherent in the contents of the Customer class. Also, it hides data access concerns behind your data access layer class, so consumers just deal with pure lists and objects rather than anything related to data access.